# How to capture events from a dynamically created button control in asp.net?

Tags: button

How can a program capture <del>generates</del> events from a dynamically created button control in asp.net?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Button ButtonDeleteFromDB = new Button();
>
> ButtonDeleteFromDB.Text = "Delete";
>
> ButtonDeleteFromDB.ID = "btnDeleteFromDB" + ctrlCount.ToString();
>
> ButtonDeleteFromDB.Click += new EventHandler(ButtonDeleteFromDB_Click);

Call the event in foll manner :

> private void ButtonDeleteFromDB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {  }

Answer (score 3):

You can attach the event programmatically:

```
Button myButton = new Button();
myButton.Click += new ClickEventHandler...etc
```